OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application - Selenium
Working with selenium, I wanted to work on a script that ran absolutely fine in the past, but suddenly doesn't.
Someone here has had the same problem in the past, and it was an error with python itself. Other than uninstalling and reinstalling python, I don't know what would fix it. I haven't changed anything in the script or with python, and so I can't imagine where the problem comes from.
**Both my python and dll are 64 bit
The code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

The error message:
"C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 208, in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child      
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application   
PS C:\Users\19DelgadoJos\Desktop\Code\videomaker> 


This type of problem can occur when Python's subprocess module runs external executables:OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
First you need to check your programming environment, is your python 32-bit version? This problem is usually caused by using 64-bit Python, in which case the solution is to reinstall the 32-bit Python version.
You may want to check if you import a C++ library dll. Generally speaking, it is because the number of python bits is not the same as the number of dll bits, dll is 32-bit, and python is 64-bit. Check yourself to see if these two parts correspond.
Also, if you are using Anaconda to manage the environment, it may be possible to install a 32-bit version of python, but anaconda and other environments are using a 64-bit version.
If you install it once with the original 32-bit python pip, all python programs will not run (and anaconda's python core will fail).
The solution is to delete the python folder of the pip installation path, generally in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python, which the python folder can be deleted.
I hope it was helpful.

Hi, thanks for the reply, i've checked and my python is definetly 64 bit. However, i've opened multiple dll files and they all say 'PE dt', which according to everywhere means that's 64 bit too. Additionally, if the versions were different the whole time, wouldn't this problem have arisen in the past? Thanks for your help!
